# Creating Test Accounts in PayPal sandbox returns error message

Tags: paypal

After I've logged into developer.paypal.com, and access Applications/Sandbox Accounts, and click "Create Account" to add personal users to my sandbox accounts, I get the error message seen below. The total records increments, but the additional accounts don't display, and I can't log back into the Sandbox using the credentials I've created.

Anyone have an idea as to what's the issue?

[image]

Comment: Are you still having an issue? What fields are you filling out?

Comment: Yes, actually. Here's the interesting thing; I also have a personal (business) developer account, in addition to the account I'm using for the business I'm working with. Same browser (Chrome, BTW), same computer, everything. I'm able to log in under my own account, and create test accounts with absolutely no problem. 

I log out, clear my cache files, log back in under our company business account, and attempt to create test accounts, using the same test values, and the errors occur - no joy on test accounts.  We're taking our app into testing now, so it's getting critical we resolve this.

Comment: What are the exact steps you're following to create the Sandbox accounts from your business account? Does the business account e-mail address have a special character in the domain?

Comment: Steps:
1. Log into developer.paypal.com
2. Click on "Applications"
3. Click on "Sandbox Accounts"
4. Click large blue "Create Account" button, upper right
5. Enter values (wait for confirmation that test e-mail acct. is "available")
6. Click large blue "Create Account" button
7. Get the following error message:
We're sorry but something went wrong.Please delete this account and try again.

Comment: Update: just tried it again, and got a test account to work; is there an issue with using an underscore (ex:john_user@domain.com)? I used underscores in the test e-mail accounts for my personal developer account, so I have no idea why it would make a difference for the company developer account.

Comment: Hand to heaven: now it makes a test account *and* throws the error message: "We're sorry but something went wrong. Please delete this account and try again." This screen could use better error handling.

Comment: The Sandbox can be fussy. Adding special characters messes up the account creation process. Have you cleared your cache and cookies since the account creation started working for you? I'm not aware of any current issues with account creation. I can research it further.

Comment: The strange part is that I was able to create test accounts that had an underscore with the same browser for one developer account, but not for the other.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, and also needed to put in the fields for 1st and last name, which the Test Account create form says are optional.  So, password needs to be complex, amount needs to be in there, and first and last name need to be specified for this error not to be thrown.

Comment: I have done all this and can't make it work. Complex password, Amount=1000, Enter first and last name.

Comment: Worked for me. Also choose matercard as payment card and put in a additional comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try entering Paypal balance value between 1 and 5000 while creating a test account. I too had the same issue and this is how I resolved it.

> PayPal balanc: While this field is optional, it’s a good idea to
>   create test accounts with positive bank balances. Enter an integer
>   value between 1 and 5000.

Source : http://believeinmiraclesx.wordpress.com/2013/03/15/paypal-sandbox-were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong-please-delete-this-account-and-try-again/

Answer (score 3):

For me, it seems this issue was caused by password validation. Try using a more complex password.

Comment: This answer should be a comment.